# Select2 - Change name="param" to other name for post request

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I have the following search box for getting data from backend:

`<select class="form-control kt-select2" id="megaagent_rainmaker_select" name="param" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%"></select>`

This is my select2 javascript code:

```
var rainmakerSelect = function () {
    // Private functions
    var demos = function () {
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        // multi select
        $('#megaagent_rainmaker_select').select2({
            language: "es",
            placeholder: "Escriba y seleccione",
            allowClear: true,
            maximumSelectionLength: 1,
            ajax: {
                url: '/admin/megaagent/getrainmaker',
                type: "get",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 150,
                data: function (params) {
                  return {
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    search: params.term // search term
                  };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                  return {
                    results: response
                  };
                },
                cache: true
              }
        });

    }

    return {
        init: function () {
            demos();
        }
    };
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    rainmakerSelect.init();
});
```

I get results returned and I can select one without problem.

After I select a value, I send update request to backend, this is my payload:

```
{
"_token": "bPl0hZJQxw5wAxNCqVOOKqrXXwkD5AZZOFPumrpC",
"mc_id": "11",
"megaagent_id": "16",
"megaagent_name": "David Cortada",
"megaagent_business_name": "bsame cambio",
"megaagent_uma_id": "umaid",
"megaagent_api_key": "apikey",
"param": "963",
"megaagent_phone_number": "phone",
"megaagent_email": "email",
"megaagent_address": "address",
"megaagent_facebook": "fb",
"megaagent_instagram": "inst",
"megaagent_twitter": "twi",
"megaagent_linkedin": "link",
"megaagent_image": "image",
"megaagent_status": "Activo"
}
```

What I want to achieve is to change **param** name to other on post request (example: `"megaagent_rainmaker_id" = "963",`.

I changed it in `<select name="param">` but that breaks the search, no results are returned when I type in search box.

Does anyone knows the solution for this?

Regards

Comment: The question is why? What are you actually trying to achieve by renaming the form field?

Comment: I'm trying to change the name so it can be called as the field in database so as not to chnage it's name when is recieved in controller

Comment: I'm still not sure I totally understand what you're saying, but I don't think what you're trying to do is a good idea. The `<select name="param">` should not really change, and you can handle whatever logic you need in the controller itself.